# Recompose bubble and add custom elements to content

Tags: botframework, web-chat

Is there a way to recompose the bubble itself? In our bot we give the user the ability to rate a message. For that we've created a star-rater (1 to 5 stars) to be displayed at the bottom of some messages. Using activityMiddleware I'm able to wrap the bubble with a custom element, but that does not allow me to place the rater at the bottom within the bubble.

Comment: why not repaint the bubble and style your custom element as bubble

Comment: What exactly do you mean by saying 'repaint the bubble'? Do you mean that I handle those activities in the middleware and return my own bubble component with my own styling? If so, this would imply that I have to implement the styling behaviour on my own so that it is always consistent with the BF bubble styling. I'd like to avoid this, if possible.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand you but you said you wrapped the bubble with a custom element. Why not make the custom element the bubble and make the extiing bubble transparent

Comment: Ah, ok, got it. How can I make my custom element the bubble?